# async callback returning array in place of object

Tags: javascript, async.js

I am using async node library to process some data. It acting wired , some times it is returning `array` with 2 element first as `undefined` and other time as as one element having the result .. Here is the sample code

```
let async =  require('async');
class Foo {
    getFoo(req, callback) {
        let self = this;
        async.waterfall( [
            self._foo.bind(self, req),
            self._bar.bind(self),
            self._foobar.bind(self)
        ] , (err, result)=> {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            console.log(result);
            return callback(null, result);
        }); 
     } 
}
```

I am using the above class in another file
    let Foo =  require('foo');

```
let req = {};
let seriesProcessArr = [];
let foo =  new Foo();
seriesProcessArr.push(foo.getFoo.bind(foo,req));
async.series( seriesProcessArr , (err, result) => {
           if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(result);
});
```

Firstly the `result` should have an object, in place of that I am getting an array. Secondly some times has `undefined` as it first element.

Comment: `result` is an array because you are using [`async.series`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series), which collects results.

Comment: You will get `undefined` when `_foobar` has an `undefined` result or when any of the functions report an error - you're logging `result` regardless of that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`result` is an array because you are using `async.series`, which collects results.

courtesy: @Bergi (please read the comment)

Comment: Answering by copy pasting @Bergi’s comment ? And without giving him any credit ? Seriously ?

Comment: @user3210641: upvoted the comment . copy pasted the comment to acknowledge that comment is the answer.